# How to use Custom Identity Provider with the build in policy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to use Custom Identity Provider with the build in policy? Is there any link available that describes the steps.

I have already configured the InBuilt policy with the custom Identity providers. But I do see errors.

http://localhost:3000/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+An+exception+has+occurred.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+90203a00-742c-4cff-b975-d6c92fcdcb81%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-10-05+09%3a18%3a38Z%0d%0a

Not sure what is missing
Thanks!

Comment: Hi prateek, are you referring to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure AD B2C Policy with Identity Providers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789839/azure-ad-b2c-policy-with-identity-providers-not-working)