# Azure AD B2C Policy with Identity Providers not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a policy that internally uses a Identity provider. On clicking run now I see the below error

http://localhost:3000/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+An+exception+has+occurred.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+84fa6f8d-6aac-4588-9d26-fd987c31ebc0%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-10-13+05%3a26%3a26Z%0d%0a

I am using a Inbuilt policy. the Policy uses a Identity provider that connects to other Azure AD. The reply urls on the AD's  application are set same.
What could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: You Should provide more details. Not just redirected error. Place which policy (custom or builtin) and which IDP and all the configurations except sensitive info

Comment: @Ramakrishna edited the question. Please check if that helps you.

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom it have example to connect Azure AD from AD B2C and you can simply do that from custom policies

Comment: After making the above chnages I see this error

"http://localhost:3000/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90037%3a+An+error+occurred+while+processing+the+request.+Please+contact+administrator+of+the+site+you+are+trying+to+access.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+dd58a43c-76c5-4794-bbd3-5428898020be%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-10-13+08%3a06%3a37Z%0d%0a"

Comment: It should work may be any configuration mistake. Can you check the steps again and try?

Comment: I have checked  but it doesn't workout. The button of other directory does appears but clicking on that gives the above error

Answer (score 0):

The error http://localhost:3000 means you already successful sign in your app, it just redirects to your app reply URL. Because you didn't run localhost:3000, so the return prompts "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks！

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, please help mark it, thanks!